# Marker Clusterer Plus change icon on hover

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

How can I dynamically change the Icon used for a specific Cluster in [Marker Clusterer Plus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html) for Google Maps V3?

The markers do not seem to expose any methods at all to modify them. I need to do something like this (or equivalent).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, "mouseover", function (cluster) {
  cluster.setIcon(hoverIcon);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, "mouseout", function (cluster) {
  cluster.setIcon(normalIcon);
});
```

Comment: The link to the library 'Marker Clusterer Plus' is not working. Can you provide the link?

Comment: This is probably it: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16):

There is a reference to the div-element that represents the cluster. The first child of this div is the img-element, change the src of this image:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster,'mouseover',function(c){
      c.clusterIcon_.div_.firstChild.src='hoverIconPath'});

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster,'mouseout',function(c){
      c.clusterIcon_.div_.firstChild.src='normalIconPath'});
```

Comment: Thanks! That actually works pretty well. However, I meant a way to change the complete `Style`, i.e. modify the url, font color, size, etc. Also, it's a shame that the only way to do it is to chain two private methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is some changing in last google maps.

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
    cluster.clusterIcon_.div_.style.backgroundImage = 'url("linktoyourimage")'})
```

Image icon moved to background.

Answer (score 0):

for me the following path worked:
`cluster.clusterIcon.div.firstChild.src`