# markerclustererplus css change on hover

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm working with Google Maps API v3 and MarkerClustererPlus library. I would prefer not using the raster icons but rendering the bubbles using `styles` and `ClusterClass` properties of MarkerClusterer object. This is my `style` object in JS code:

```
var myClusterStyle = [{
        url: './icons/placeholder.png', //1x1 transparent png
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        textColor: '#636363',
        textSize: 12
}];
```

And the CSS class:

```
.cluster {
    background-color: #EAE6DE;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #ACCCFD;
    position: absolute; 
}
```

So, these are the grey bubbles with blue border.

My question is:

I would like to change some properties of an individual bubble on mouseover, let's say change the color or add the shadow. Could I change the CSS class of the bubble? I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and now I'm stuck. I have this event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mc,'mouseover',function(c){

    c.clusterIcon_.setValues({className_:'clusterHover'});
});
```

and it really changes the CSS class option of the bubble but the display doesn't change... following `mc.repaint(), c.clusterIcon_.draw()` don't help.

I have seen this thread:
[Marker Clusterer Plus change icon on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454582/marker-clusterer-plus-change-icon-on-hover)
but this is for changing the icon, not the style properties. Is this really possible without modifying the library? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may set the class of the div directly:

```
c.clusterIcon_.div_.className='clusterHover'
```

But it would be much easier when you use the `:hover`-pseudo-class

```
.cluster:hover {
    /* some styles */
}
```